# GTK3 and cairo too slow

Tags: c, gtk3, cairo

I've made a very simple animation with GTK3 and cairo and it's too slow for this simple graphics. I don't understand why it's so slow. I tried to use *gtk_widget_queue_draw_area*, but result is the same, nothing changes.
Who can explain me, why it's so slow and how can i fix it?

Here's the program:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <cairo.h>

void draw(GtkWidget* widget, cairo_t* cr)
{
    static int width, height,
               posX = 0,
               vX = 1;

    GtkWidget* window = gtk_widget_get_toplevel(widget);
    gtk_window_get_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), &width, &height);

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
    cairo_set_line_width(cr, 1);

    cairo_rectangle(cr, posX, height/2, 1, 1);
    cairo_stroke(cr);

    if(posX + vX >= width || posX + vX == 0)
        vX = -vX;
    posX += vX;

    gtk_widget_queue_draw(window);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    GtkWidget* window;
    GtkWidget* darea;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), darea);

    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 500, 400);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw", G_CALLBACK(draw), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
}
```

Comment: Maybe `gtk_queue_draw` is effectively ignored inside a `draw` signal callback. Try running it from a timeout with a small period between calls. I suspect queue draw is ignored precisely to avoid mistakes causing unintended "animations". The `draw` callback is supposed to actually do the drawing, not defer it for later, so calling `gtk_queue_draw` in the middle of it sounds like an incorrect implementation.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. I using a stopwatch measured the dot moving across the window to be 8.3 s. Using a refresh rate of 60 Hz, the dot moving 1 pixel each frame and the window width of 500 pixels this works out to take 8.3333 s. So, everything is OK. To increase the speed you will need to increase the distance moved per frame. In your code this would be to increase the value of vX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should use timers**, e.g. [g_timeout_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add). You could register with `g_timeout_add` your new function `redraw` called every 0.05 seconds (e.g. every 50 milliseconds), and that `redraw` should not only draw things but also return `TRUE` to be restarted 50 milliseconds later. You'll find out that such a 50 millisecond delay is probably too small, and you surely want to increase it.

(notice that your program takes only 3% of CPU time, measured with [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html)... on Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64 on a Intel i5-4690S, so it is not too slow; the computer spends 97% of time waiting! remember also that the human eyes don't see a lot faster than 30 to 60 Hz most of the time)

**There is no animation code in your program** (because any animation should be *periodically* run). The [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (in `gtk_main`) is called only when needed. You could want to repaint your window only partially.

Your approach is wrong. You don't want to repeat the drawing with `gtk_widget_queue_draw`, you want it to happen again periodically (e.g. call that `gtk_widget_queue_draw` from a new `redraw` routine registered with `g_timeout_add`). You'll tune that period experimentally.

You could also use [gtk_widget_add_tick_callback](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-add-tick-callback) (as commented by c-smile). I don't think you need it (because I guess your animation might then run too fast).

Study the source code of some [GTK examples](https://github.com/steshaw/gtk-examples) (notably the [clock](https://github.com/steshaw/gtk-examples/tree/master/ch10.gdk.clock/clock) example). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48424320/841108) and [that](https://www.cairographics.org/threaded_animation_with_cairo/). Look into the [custom drawing](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s05.html) example, and into the source of [aclock](https://github.com/mertensj/aclock).

<sup>(your program is not too slow, but your `draw` is probably called not frequently enough; there is no code to repeat it; you should [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and compile your code with `-Wall -g` passed to `gcc` - in addition of other flags provided by `pkg-config`)</sup>

Comment: "There is no animation code in your program", check `gtk_widget_queue_draw(window);`

Comment: But nothing repeats the drawing. You need to use timers, you can't avoid using them, if you want to have some animations. Computers are quick!

Comment: gtk_widget_queue_draw() -> gdk_window_invalidate_region() ->

Invalidates the area of widget defined by region by calling gdk_window_invalidate_region() on the widget’s window and all its child windows. Once the main loop becomes idle (after the current batch of events has been processed, roughly), the window will receive expose events for the union of all regions that have been invalidated.

Comment: No, the window won't recieve a lot of expose events. These are given by your X11 or Wayland server, and if you don't more *other* windows (above and around yours) you won't get expose events. If you want some animation, you should have a timeout. Run your code in the debugger, put a breakpoint on your `draw` routine: you'll be surprised how *rarely* it is called.

Comment: This is all about incorrect statement "There is no animation code in your program".  There is such loop as you see. On Windows/GTK TS's code is roughly this: `case WM_PAINT : InvalidateRect(hwnd,NULL,0)` that will cause WM_PAINT to come to the widget with VSync FPS (60 or so).

Comment: But you are not on Windows, but probably on Linux. Again, **use the debugger**

Comment: "use the debugger" for what? And "use timers" for what exactly ? Animations? Timers cannot be used for animations as there is no strong frequency guarantee. Please don't give wrong advices. There is a `gtk_widget_add_tick_callback()` to request animation frames in GTK.

Comment: The debugger is certainly useful to understand *when* `draw` is called

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I tried to use g_timeout_add with 1ms timeout, but speed doesn't increase.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Also i used `gtk_widget_add_tick_callback()` but nothing changes. Maybe I don't uderstand how to use it.

Comment: @c-smile how should i use `gtk_widget_add_tick_callback()`? I tried, but it doesn't give the result. Should I use it in main function or how?

Comment: -1: "Your approach is wrong." Got a source for that? Because first, with gtk's frame clock, queuing a draw from within a draw should work, as it schedules a draw at exactly the right time next frame. 2. Using timeouts + callbacks gives no synchronisation whatsoever with vsyncs, and also involves guessing the screen refresh rate. 3. The recommended approach is actually to use frame clock tick callbacks, not a timeout.